Investing descargar precios de una ctyivo entre fechas
Estoy intentando desde Excel VBA acceder a los datos historicos entre dos fecha de varios activos en la pagina Investing.com. Concretamente
https://www.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-food---beverage-pr
https://www.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-banks-pr
y algunos otros mas.
He consultado a traves de "TalkAI" un posible codigo para este proposito y este ha sido el resultado:
Sub DescargarDatosHistoricos()

    Dim XMLHttp As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Tickers As Variant
    Dim FechaInicio As Date
    Dim FechaFin As Date
    Dim i As Byte

    Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    Tickers = Array("SX7P", "SX3P") 'Agrega aquí los tickers adicionales que desees
    
    FechaInicio = DateSerial(2021, 1, 1) 'Fecha de inicio de los datos históricos
    FechaFin = DateSerial(2021, 12, 31) 'Fecha de fin de los datos históricos

    For i = LBound(Tickers) To UBound(Tickers)

        URL = "https://www.investing.com/indices/" & Tickers(i) & "-historical-data"

        XMLHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
        XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        XMLHttp.send

        Dim HTMLDoc As Object
        Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText

        Dim Tabla As Object
        Set Tabla = HTMLDoc.getElementById("curr_table")

        Dim Fila As Object
        Dim Columna As Object
        Dim filaNumero As Integer

        filaNumero = 2

        For Each Fila In Tabla.Rows
            If Fila.RowIndex > 0 Then
                For Each Columna In Fila.Cells
                    Cells(filaNumero, Columna.ColumnIndex).Value = Columna.innerText
                Next Columna
                filaNumero = filaNumero + 1
            End If
        Next Fila

    Next i

End Sub

Este codigo deja de funcionar por falta de un objeto en la sentencia "Set Tabla = HTMLDoc.getElementById("curr_table")" y no soy capaz de solucionarlo.
En consecuencia escribo este post para ver si alguien me puede hechar una ayuda para poder solucionarlo, y a si poder ejectuar el codigo con el proposito que necesito.
Gracias anticipadas por vuestra ayuda y colaboracion.
Saludos,
José Miguel.

Al menos en la página que diste de ejemplo no existe ningún elemento con el id curr_table, por otro lado, me da la impresión que el método de scrapping que estas usando no es el adecuado para una página  dinámica como esta, te sugiero que investigues por el lado de https://www.selenium.dev/

Saludos Patricio. Gracias por tu respuesta. El elemento "curr_table" me lo ha facilitado el codigo que he pedido  a "TalkAi". Yo no lo habria sabido ni buscarlo ni encontrarlo por que este nivel de programación es muy alto para mis conocimientos actuales, al igual que con la referencia que indicas "selenium.dev" que no se lo que es. Lo que busco, abiertamente, es algun codigo que me permita acceder a mi proposito de poder descargarme la información que preciso. Si puedes ayudarme, te lo agradeceria mucho, y si no lo haces pues tambien por tomarte tu tiempo leyendo mi consulta. Gracias.
